# Unable to use eclipse to test automate android apps with appium and selenium

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, android-studio, appium

I am newbie in automation. I was trying to set up appium and selenium to test automate android applications. But when I checked, I found out that Android has stopped supporting eclipse, and instead is going with android studio. So which tool I should use for mobile automation? Should I use android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate your test using eclipse , you need not to configure android with eclipse :

Following software should be configured in system :

1. ANDROID SDK - Search in google you will get links to download it
2. You have to set ANDROID_HOME in your system once you downloaded this sdk.
3. To verify your android home is set properly you can hit adb devices
4. JDK (Java Development Kit)
5. TestNG
6. Eclipse
7. Selenium Server JAR
8. Webdriver Language Binding Library APPIUM For Window or mac
9. APK App
10. Node.js

(Not Required - Whenever Appium server is installed, it by
        default comes with "Node.exe" & NPM. It's included in Current
        version of Appium.)

To view ui element you can use uiautomatorviewer.bat available in Android SDK.